# addClass function doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I want to add the `effect` class to any existing classes that the my `input type="submit"` already has, as long as the action contains the string `special`.

I'm using the following code:

```
<body>

<form action="/go/special" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" class="zzz" value="click me"></form>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    // find all forms that have "special" in the action, find their input, and add the class
    $('form[action*="special"] input[type="submit"]').addClass('effect');
});
</script>
</body>
```

If it will work properly output should be:

```
<form action="/go/special" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" class="zzz effect" value="click me"></form>
```

But it remains:

```
<form action="/go/special" method="POST" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" class="zzz" value="click me"></form>
```

Comment: Works fine [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6x80vabm/1) Either the element doesn't exist when your code runs or something else is wrong like an error being thrown

Comment: @charlietfl may be you should remove the class effect from html in your demo :)

Comment: I tested your code and it is working correctly for me.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef oops...I didn't see that...fiddle link updated and still working

Comment: I tested this exact same code, once again, with 2 browsers, and it doesn't work... how could it be?

Comment: @rockyraw provide demo that doesn't work. Is there any ajax involved? Are any errors showing in dev tols console?

Comment: @charlietfl Oh my bad. I didn't realize that using view-source would show me the code before the script runs. thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This script is working correctly for me. It's possible that something weird is going on with your testing environment, and to eliminate a few possible confounding elements, I would try wrapping your script in a `$( document ).ready(function() {}` call.

No this shouldn't be necessary, and others are free to chime in with style tips, but the only times I have experienced an error like this, it was with the eventing malfunctioning for some reason.